# Proof for integral representation of Lambert W function

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, lambert-w

The Lambert W function satisfies the identity

$$W(z)e^{W(z)}=z.$$

How do you prove that

$$
W(z)
= \frac{z}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{(1-\nu \cot(\nu))^2+\nu^2}{z+\nu \csc(\nu)e^{-\nu\cot(\nu)}} \, \mathrm{d}\nu
$$

where $z$ is a real number and  $z\geq-\frac{1}{e}$?

Comment: @MarkViola I found it on a Wikipedia article. The source the article gave was [this](http://www.orcca.on.ca/LambertW/)

Answer (score 8):

A proof using complex analysis is provided on Theorem 3.1 on the article ["Stieltjes, Poisson and other integral representations for functions of Lambert W"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5640) by German A. Kalugin, David J. Jeffrey, and Robert M. Corless. However, there are some preliminaries in the article not necessary for the proof for this theorem, hence I will try to summarize.

---

The proof uses the fact that the function $W(z)/z$ is holomorphic on the domain $D=\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, -1/e]$. By Cauchy's integral formula, it follows that:
$$\frac{W(z)}{z}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{W(t)}{t(t-z)}~dt$$
where $C$ is a positively oriented keyhole contour, as follows:

[image]

Letting $r\to 0$ and $R\to \infty$, it can be shown that this reduces to (it can be shown that the contributions of each circle to the integral is zero):
$$\frac{W(z)}{z}=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{-1/e} \frac{W(t)}{t(t-z)}~dt+\int_{-1/e}^{-\infty} \frac{\overline{W(t)}}{t(t-z)}~dt\right]$$
Note that in the above we have used that for $x\in D$, we have that $W(\overline{x})=\overline{W(x)}$. Additionally, we have that for all $w\in \mathbb{C}$ that $\Im(w)=\frac{w-\overline{w}}{2i}$, hence the integral reduces to:
$$\frac{W(z)}{z}=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{-1/e} \frac{\Im(W(t))}{t(t-z)}~dt=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-1/e}^{-\infty} \frac{\Im(W(t))}{t(z-t)}~dt$$
The article then proceeds to use the change of variable $\nu=\Im(W(t))$. The variables can be shown to be related by:
$$t=-\nu \csc(\nu) e^{-\nu \cot(\nu)}$$
Differentiating gives:
$$dt=-\csc(\nu)e^{-\nu \cot(\nu)}(\nu^2+(1-\nu\cot(\nu))^2)~d\nu$$
Hence, it follows that (since $t=-1/e$ gets mapped to $\nu=0$ and $t\to -\infty$ gets mapped to $\nu=\pi$):
$$\frac{W(z)}{z}=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\nu^2+(1-\nu\cot(\nu))^2}{z+\nu \csc(\nu) e^{-\nu \cot(\nu)}}~d\nu$$
Since the integrand is even with respect to $\nu$, we obtain the desired result.

Comment: :p not so hard once you see the first integral, but knowing where to start without it is not so trivial +1