# Is there any example of a real-analytic approach to evaluate a definite integral (with an elementary integrand) whose value involves Lambert W?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, lambert-w, elementary-functions

I have never seen a real-analytic approach before to evaluate integrals of the form below
$$\int_a^b\text{elementary function}(x)\,dx=\text{constant involving}\,W(\cdot)\,\text{in its simplest form}\tag1.$$

For instance, on MSE, all use the residue theorem:

- [$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^x+1\over (e^x-x+1)^2+\pi^2}\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^x+1\over (e^x+x+1)^2+\pi^2}\mathrm dx=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113205/int-infty-inftyex1-over-ex-x12-pi2-mathrm-dx-int-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Interesting integral related to the Omega Constant/Lambert W Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/interesting-integral-related-to-the-omega-constant-lambert-w-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{1+2\cos x+x\sin x}{1+2x\sin x +x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{1+\Omega}$ where $\Omega e^\Omega=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331600/prove-that-int-0-infty-frac12-cos-xx-sin-x12x-sin-x-x2dx-frac-pi?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Proof for integral representation of Lambert W function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347447/proof-for-integral-representation-of-lambert-w-function)
- [Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1+\frac{2\cos x}{x^2} +\frac{1}{x^4}) \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433252/evaluate-int-0-infty-ln1-frac2-cos-xx2-frac1x4-dx)

And the same applies to some of the wider literature I have come across:

- [Stieltjes, Poisson and other integral representations for functions of Lambert W](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.5640.pdf)
- [An Integral Representation of the Lambert $W$ Function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.02480.pdf) **Note:** the proof is real-analytic, but the very first line assumes the validity of an integral identity which was only proven using complex analysis (Hankel contour).

So, my question is this:

Does anyone know of a proof of an identity of the form in $(1)$ that involves only real analysis (i.e. does not assume the existence of $\sqrt{-1}$)?

Comment: Does $\int\limits_{\infty }^1 e^{1-x}\,dx=W\left(-\frac{1}{e}\right)=-1$ count?

Comment: @StevenClark No, which is the reason I added "in its simplest form" (or "in most simplified form" before this edit) so that we don't have trivial cases like $\int_0^12x\,dx=1=W(10)/W(10)$.

Comment: My example is less trivial than your example, and is $\int\limits_{\infty }^1 e^{1-x}\,dx$ not a valid integral representation of $W\left(-\frac{1}{e}\right)$?

Comment: @StevenClark I think there is a bit of misunderstanding -- I'm trying to find a valid integral representation (elementary integrand) for values of a constant involving $W(\cdot)$ such that it cannot be simplified to a constant that doesn't involve $W$. So $1/(1+W(2))$ would be valid, but constants like $W(-1/e)=-1$ or $\sin W(3e^3)^2=\sin9$ would not.

Comment: Does one also have to prove a result involving $W(x)$ has no closed form that does't involve the $W(x)$ function?

Comment: @StevenClark No, I think as long as your $x$ does not obviously simplify to $ye^y$ for some elementary $y$ then it's accepted (like obvious manipulations of $W((\sqrt2+1)e^{\sqrt2+1})$. Since otherwise we'd be running into much deeper holes involving Schanuel's conjecture.

Comment: Do you consider numerical integration a real-analytic approach? Some of your examples can be evaluated via numerical integration, but some of your examples also simplify which seems inconsistent with your desire to find an example that doesn't simplify. Excluding results that simplify seems rather arbitrary assuming one can show the example is inherently related to the Lambert W function. Trivial cases such as $\frac{W(10)}{W(10)}$ don't generally meet this criteria, but it seems to me $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^x+1\over (e^x-x+1)^2+\pi^2}\mathrm dx=1$ does meet this criteria.

Comment: @StevenClark No (I'm looking for an analytical proof rather than numerical). In that example, I'm actually not referring to the end result $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^x+1\over (e^x-x+1)^2+\pi^2}\,dx=1$ but rather the lemma $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a^2\,dx}{(e^x-ax-b)^2+(a\pi)^2}=\frac{1}{1+W\left(\frac{1}{a}e^{-b/a}\right)}$ in Jack's answer, which he said was evaluated only through the residue theorem. To qualify as an answer here, an example would be to prove the latter identity using real analysis when, say, $a=2$ and $b=3$, since $W(e^{-3/2}/2)$ doesn't have an obvious simplification.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Each thread you linked used either contour integration, residue theorem, Cauchy integral theorem, or another [complex analysis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexAnalysis.html) theorem. Is a solution without these, but still using complex numbers, like in transforms or summation formulas, ok?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash No, the proof must not use the fact that $\sqrt{-1}$ exists.